# How to calculate if a point is within a circle

Tags: c++, math, contains

I am given a constructor:

```
Circle::Circle(const Point& c, float r) {
    x_ = c.getX();
    y_ = c.getY();
    r_ = r;
}
```

All values have been initialised as shown. In the parameter I have `Point&` - This just allows me to get the x and y coords using a function from a different class. Also, I have "r" which will take in the radius value.

Using this I want to check whether that: If o is a circle, it returns true if and only if p is on the inside or the boundary of the circle

For example,

I am given: `Point p(1,2);` & `Circle c(p,3);`

I want to check if `Point(3.9,2)` is on the inside or on the boundary of `Circle c(p,3);`

For extra reference, I will provide the `Point Constructor`:

```
Point::Point(float x, float y) {
    x_ = x;
    y_ = y;
}
```

Initialised constructor to allow me to create getter and setters for use in other classes.

In my function I have tried this :

```
bool Circle::contains(const Point& p) const {

    bool results; 
    if( ( (getX()-p.getX() ) * ( getX()-p.getX() ) ) + ( ( (getY()-p.getY() ) * ( getY()-p.getY() ) ) <= (getR()*getR())))


    {
        results = true;
    }
else {results = false;}
return results;
}
```

This did not work.

Test Case I am given:

```
    Point p(1,2);
Circle c(p,3);
if (!c.contains(p)) errorOut_("c does not contain p?",1);
if (!c.contains(Point(3.9,2))) errorOut_("c does not contain (3.9,2)?",1);
if (!c.contains(Point(3.1,4.1))) errorOut_("c does not contain (3.1,4.1)?",1);
if (!c.contains(Point(-1.1,4.1))) errorOut_("c does not contain (-1.1,4.1)?",1);
if (!c.contains(Point(-1.1,-0.1))) errorOut_("c does not contain (-1.1,-0.1)?",1);
if (!c.contains(Point(3.1,-0.1))) errorOut_("c does not contain (3.1,-0.1)?",1);
if (c.contains(Point(3.2,4.2))) errorOut_("c contains (3.2,4.2)?",1);
if (c.contains(Point(-1.2,4.2))) errorOut_("c contains (-1.2,4.2)?",1);
if (c.contains(Point(-1.2,-0.2))) errorOut_("c contains (-1.2,-0.2)?",1);
if (c.contains(Point(3.2,-0.2))) errorOut_("c contains (3.2,-0.2)?",1);
```

The result:

```
fail1: c contains (-1.2,4.2)?
fail1: c contains (-1.2,-0.2)?
fail1: c contains (3.2,-0.2)?
```

Comment: See that line of your code where it's really hard to match up the parentheses?  You matched them up wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether point lies inside circle, you need to implement this formula (strict `<` if you don't need points at circumerence):

```
 (px-cx)*(px-cx) + (py-cy)*(py-cy) <= r*r
```

Squared distance from point to center should be less than squared radius (to avoid sqrt calculation)

For your example

```
(3.9-1)^2+(2-2)^2 = 8.41 < 3*3=9   - inside
```

Corrected your function:

```
bool Circle::contains(const Point& p) const {
    return ( ( (getX()-p.getX() ) * ( getX()-p.getX() ) ) + 
             ( ( (getY()-p.getY() ) * ( getY()-p.getY() ) ) <= (getR()*getR())))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to make clear (pointX - circleX)^2 etc etc..?

Comment: Yes. exactly. But don't use `pow` (unless compiler optimizes `pow(x,2)`)

Comment: Can you please check the question again. I have tried your solution

Comment: You missed `return` in the function. Added correction

Comment: Sorry, I have added the test case i was given.

Comment: Possible issue - you don't initialize local var `results`, so when `if` fails, `results` contains junk. Try my function

Comment: Yes thank you however I still get the same result.

Comment: math gives sum 9.68 for the first wrong example, definitely large than 9. https://ideone.com/fMBS8L

Comment: Thank you soo much. It appears when I try to call the function instead of the variable it will not work.